# How do you remove the default whitespacing around text in a h1 Tag

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have been trying to remove the default white space around text that is sitting inside of my h1 tag. I have already used margin, padding, border, and line-spacing to remove the whitespace.

Any ideas on how to do this or if it is possible?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I2Dl.png)

Thanks

Comment: If what you're referring to is the white space above and below what appears to be selected text, I do not think this is possible; however, you might look into the line height property of CSS to reduce its size?

Comment: share html code please

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am trying do to @jake.toString

Answer (score 2):

The property you're looking for is `line-height`. The white space that appears when you highlight the text is technically being considered as part of the text, which is why setting properties like `margin` and `padding` to 0 doesn't make a difference.